# how do i remove a class from my vb solution when the class does not show up in the references?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have a project which was started coding in Visual Basic 2017 and now in 2019. There are 3 classes that I wrote into the project in 2017 that I no longer use. When I went to remove them they don't show up in the My Project list instead they are in a different directory than the main project is in ( the directory name is 'My Projects'). I do not refer to these classes in the program but the compiler still looks for them and throws an error saying it cant find them. I tried moving them to the same directory as the main program is in but that created more problems. Now, I have noticed as I add a new class or method it puts it in the 'My Projects' directory and it does not show up in the solution list. Questions, 1, why are this new class code being put into a different directory, and 2, how do I remove the old ones entirely from my solution. They are not on the Projects list so I can't do the normal delete as I have done in the past. The directory tree for the solution is:

C:\Visual Basic 2017\MyMovies-2019\MyMovies-2019

directory for the files I have a problem with is:

C:\Visual Basic 2017\MyMovies-2019\MyMovies-2019\My Projects

I have no idea how they ended up there when 5 other class codes are in the main directory.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really follow your question.  But class are added to a project via the references. To remove a class, you will need to delete the reference.  Take a look in your project reference tree and delete the one you don't want.

[image]